# Create .SO files on Linux without using PIC (position independent code) (x86 32bit)

Tags: linux, assembly, dll, dynamic-linking, relocation

As far as I know, x86 assembly code is very much constrained by the limited amount of registers.

When I learnt that on Linux, to create a .so file, one has to specify the -fPIC command line argument to gcc in order to create position independent code, I couldn't believe it first.

As far as I know, the elf file format supports relocations, just like the - in my eyes much better - Windows DLL system works: On Windows the linker relocates all the offsets in the DLLs, if this is necessary.

I think that the time needed to load a SO-file or DLL-file, and also the amount of memory used to keep differently relocated .so-files around is not as bad as the lack of a whole register all the time which points to the GOT and having all this indirect jumps.

I also don't care at all for ALSR etc. for the applications I have in mind were I only care about having code in a library to be optimized as much as possible.

1) Why does Linux not support more dynamic library loading like Windows which should produce much much more performant code?

So far I have found no real explanation for it. Just some things like that it would be so very bad and slow to relocate code (Of course, for loading a word processor on a desktop machine, it matters how fast it loads, I fully accept that. But for a computationally intensive server process (not processing malicious data from the internet), I'd like to have all the performance and registers I can get!

2) Is it possible for me to create NOT -fPIC compiled SO-files on Linux? Can I just leave the -fPIC away? Is there any howto, manual or project which works on this topic and makes it possible to not waste a whole register and still load libraries dynamically?

What happens if I just drop the -fPIC when compiling a .so-file?

Comment: Are you more concerned with IA32 or x86-64? Any answer will depend on this distinction.

Comment: I am concerned with 32 Bit code and adjusted the title of the question

Comment: For computation intensive programs, it is really worth (for many reasons) to switch to 64 bits linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What happens if I just drop the `-fPIC` when compiling a `.so`-file?

The resulting shared object ELF file would (very probably) be dynamically loaded at semi-random (i.e. unpredictable) page addresses (e.g. because the `mmap` syscall will encounter [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)).

And the linker would produce a huge lot of relocation operations. So the dynamic linker (`ld.so`) would have to slowly process a big lot of relocations, so your text segment would have to be rewritten (and won't be efficiently read-only shared with other processes using the same `.so` file).

So in practice forgetting the `-fPIC` on a shared object (i.e. dynamically linked library) is most often a bad idea, even if it is possible.

Read [Drepper's HowTo do Dynamic Shared Libraries](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) paper and Wheeler's [Program Library Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)

BTW, [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) is much more costly on x86 (32 bits) than on x86-64. But it is worth the effort (probably, PIC code is at most 5 to 10% slower than non-PIC on x86 32 bits).

Comment: Thanks! It's great that ld.so can do what I want. I have read the other things you write also in other places, but I wonder if the amount of work ld.so has to do is really that important in ALL scenarios. For e.g. a server process, once everything is relocated, where is the problem? And gaining up to 10% performance because one register is not wasted and all jumps can be direct seems to be very well worth the effort in some circumstances. I wonder why I saw no text about pic and relocations which discusses that someone might rather go with runtime performance than fast load