# Linux g++: linking with static libstdc++ without exporting it

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-objects, libstdc++

I'm compiling a shared object (.so) that is supposed to be `LD_PRELOAD`ed into other application. I'm linking with libstdc++ and libgcc statically using `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` to avoid shard objects conflics. 
Doing this however makes my so expose everything in libstdc++ as public symbols. When I do

```
nm -D mylib.so
```

I get a lot of stuff like

```
00000000000714e0 W _ZNKSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4gptrEv
0000000000071530 W _ZNKSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4pptrEv
00000000000714d0 W _ZNKSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5ebackEv
00000000000714f0 W _ZNKSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5egptrEv
0000000000071540 W _ZNKSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5epptrEv
0000000000071520 W _ZNKSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5pbaseEv
00000000000712a0 W _ZNKSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6getlocEv
```

This is bad since when this so will be LD_PRELOADed into a c++ application, these symbols are going to override the applications symbols, causing unexpected behaviour.

So how do I make gcc link statically to libstdc++ without exposing all of these symbols publically?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [visibility pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Visibility-Pragmas.html) and [visibility function attributes](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

You probably want to give `hidden` or `protected`  visibility.

I am not sure you are right to statically link the `libstdc++`: your resulting `mylib.so` might then contain non [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). Read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900917/841108) which explains why it could be a bad idea, and gives other useful references.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is use a version script:

http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_25.html

to declare what symbols are exported