# How to avoid recompiling all the files everytime?

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-errors, compilation

I have about 20 .cpp files and and as many .h files. When I compile I do

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o main
```

in main.cpp I start by some forward declarations and then I include all .h and .cpp files.

As a result, at every compilation, all the files must be recompiled which it uncomfortably slow. I think I would need to use `.so` and/or `.dll` files so that at future compilation, only the modified code need to be recompiled. I don't really know how to do that. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: you should look at [`CMake`](https://cmake.org/). Here is a [basic tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/).

Comment: Use a build system; suggestions are: one of the IDEs for your platform, CMake, Make

Comment: Beyond using a build system, stop including your cpp files. Compile them to object files and link the objects together. That will prevent a modification to one from requiring all others to be recompiled (indirectly because they are included). That's not to say the [SCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit) technique is not without its uses. But you clearly seem not to want it.

Comment: Use a build system like [SCons](http://scons.org) or [CMake](https://cmake.org) and make sure to configure it correctly so it can track dependencies between your files.

Comment: [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) as well.

Comment: And use forward declarations wherever possible

Comment: If you can avoid it, I suggest not using a build file builder like CMake. I suggest using the industry standard, GNU Make. Like C++, it takes some effort learning GNU Make, but it is worth the effort. And use GNU Make and GCC features for automatic dependency generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally want each [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) to be compiled separately and you might even compile them in parallel (e.g. with `make -j`, see below).

<sup>(I am guessing and hoping that you are on Linux and using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as `g++`; adapt this answer to your compiler and operating system if not.)</sup>

If you have `src1.cpp src2.cpp src3.cpp` (each containing appropriate [`#include` directives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive), probably with a common header file) you would compile `src1.cpp` into an [object file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) `src1.o` [using GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g src1.cpp -c -o src1.o
```

<sup>The `-Wall -Wextra` options asks for all warnings and some extra ones, and you really want them (to improve your code to get no warnings). The `-g` option asks for [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging information (to be able to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) later, and also to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)). The `-c` option requires only the compilation step without linking. The `-o src1.o` explicits the output object file.</sup>

Likewise, you'll compile `src2.cpp` into `src2.o`

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g src2.cpp -c -o src2.o
```

and `src3.cpp`

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -g src3.cpp -c -o src3.o
```

BTW I prefer the shorter `.cc` suffix to `.cpp`. For benchmarking purposes, enable [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) in your compiler, e.g. by adding `-O2 -march=native` after `-g`.

Finally you want to [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) all your three objects files `src1.o`, `src2.o` and `src3.o` into a `myprog` [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable):

```
g++ -g src1.o src2.o src3.o -o myprog
```

<sup>you might add additional options, e.g. to link external libraries.</sup>

Beware that [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++14) (and also C++11 and even C++17) has no real [modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) (in contrast to Ocaml or Go). So the preprocessor is used a lot, and you practically need to include a lot of code; for example, `#include <vector>` is pulling more than ten thousand lines of C++ code from standard and internal header files on my Linux/Debian desktop. This explains why C++ compilers are slow, hence I recommend avoiding too small C++ files (e.g. a source file of only a hundred C++ lines including *several* header files, that would in practice pull dozens of thousands of C++ lines from various internal headers). My preference is to define *several* related functions (and perhaps classes) in each `.cc` (or `.cpp`) source file of one or a few thousands lines of C++.

<sup>(future C++ standards, perhaps [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20), might add modules to the language; but this could be postponed...)</sup>

My recommendation is to learn to use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/). Indeed you need a [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool.

You certainly should learn how to invoke your compiler on the command line. Read about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) if you use `g++`. Order of arguments to `g++` matters a big lot.

You could use tools like [cmake](https://cmake.org/) or [meson](http://mesonbuild.com/) which generates configuration files (for `make` or `ninja`). But I recommend simpler things than `cmake` or `meson` (e.g. code your `Makefile` by hand and just use `make`). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44097986/841108) is an example of [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) for `make`.  You need to understand your build process. In some cases, you might generate some (simple) C++ file(s) during your build (e.g. with [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [Qt moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) or your own script or program emitting some C++ file).

> I think I would need to use `.so`

Not necessarily. `.so` files are shared objects, used in shared libraries. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900917/841108). You could (and probably at first, you want to) have several object files, as explained above. You might later consider making your own software [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)), but that is worthwhile only for reusable source code.

To link external libraries, you might even want to use [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) (for those packages knowing about it) which expands to appropriate build options for `g++`.

Look also into existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects for inspiration, and study their source code (including their build process). You'll find many of them in Linux distributions, and on [github](http://github.com/), [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/) and elsewhere.

Comment: This was so helpful. I found it a little hard to get those kind of very introductory informations about compilations and your easy-to-read post and the generous amount of links helped me a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> ... and then I include all .h and .cpp files.

`.cpp` files (aka translation units) aren't meant to be *included*. You should use a script or any other kind of build system, that compiles each of the `.cpp` files separately, and links all the produced `.o` object files together into the executable program.

This can be enabled to avoid to recompile all the `.cpp` files, if they aren't affected by changes in header files.